# SQL Server traffic byte code issue

Tags: sql-server

Usually SQL Server transaction is using multi-byte code like this.

```
11:29:52.925182 IP 192.168.10.9.3862 > 192.168.10.5.1433: P 4117707564:4117707692(128) ack 672638990 win 6432 <nop,nop,timestamp 771920 264690946>
0x0000:  4500 00b4 7c2a 4000 4006 28bb c0a8 0a09  E...|*@.@.(.....
0x0010:  c0a8 0a05 0f16 0599 f56f 3b2c 2817 a80e  .........o;,(...
0x0020:  8018 1920 9605 0000 0101 080a 000b c750  ...............P
0x0030:  0fc6 dd02 0101 0080 0000 0100 5300 4500  ............S.E.
0x0040:  4c00 4500 4300 5400 2000 4300 4f00 5500  L.E.C.T...C.O.U.
0x0050:  4e00 5400 2800 2a00 2900 2000 4600 5200  N.T.(.*.)...F.R.
0x0060:  4f00 4d00 2000 7300 6500 6e00 6400 5f00  O.M...s.e.n.d._.
0x0070:  7200 6500 7300 7500 6c00 7400 2000 2800  r.e.s.u.l.t...(.
0x0080:  5200 4500 4100 4400 5000 4100 5300 5400  R.E.A.D.P.A.S.T.
0x0090:  2900 2000 5700 4800 4500 5200 4500 2000  )...W.H.E.R.E...
0x00a0:  5200 4500 5300 5500 4c00 5400 3d00 2700  R.E.S.U.L.T.=.'.
0x00b0:  5300 2700                                S.'.
```

But I found sql Server sometimes use single byte like this, yesterday.

```
11:29:31.688331 IP 192.168.10.8.3989 > 192.168.10.5.1433: P 3116352293:3116352333(40) ack 2215594188 win 11788 <nop,nop,timestamp 750683 264691313>
0x0000:  4500 005c fd77 4000 4006 a7c6 c0a8 0a08  E..\.w@.@.......
0x0010:  c0a8 0a05 0f95 0599 b9bf c325 840f 48cc  ...........%..H.
0x0020:  8018 2e0c 95ac 0000 0101 080a 000b 745b  ..............t[
0x0030:  0fc6 de71 0101 0028 0000 0100 5345 4c45  ...q...(....SELE
0x0040:  4354 2043 4f55 4e54 2028 202a 2920 4652  CT.COUNT.(.*).FR
0x0050:  4f4d 204e 4f44 4543 4f44 4520            OM.NODECODE.
```

I'm working for kind of DAM solution company and this is causing some monitoring issue.
I modified my program, and I need to test.
But I don't know how to make the same situation.

Could someone let me know how to configure SQL Server client or Server?

Comment: What is a "DAM solution" company?

Comment: Google suggests that "DAM" may be "[Digital Asset Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management)". If this is what the OP is talking about, then I would even more strongly recommend that his company rethink their architecture. They would appear to be operating on the wrong level of abstraction - by several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

The protocol that's used to communicate between the client and the server is called [Tabular Data Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream):

> Tabular Data Stream (TDS) is an application layer protocol, used to transfer data between a database server and a client. It was initially designed and developed by Sybase Inc. for their Sybase SQL Server relational database engine in 1984, and later by Microsoft in Microsoft SQL Server.

Rather than you trying to reverse engineer the protocol, it would be better to either a) Use the work of others who've gone before you (e.g. freetds), or b) to follow the [*specification*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc448435.aspx), rather than coding to the quirks of a particular *implementation*.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the network protocol used by a piece of software like SQL Server is nobody's business. It's an internal implementation detail, one which they are free to change at any time, for any reason, or just because they feel like it.

I hope you have a very good reason for needing to care about the details of the protocol that a SQL Server client chooses to use to talk to a SQL Server server.

After, all, if the client is happy talking to the server, then you certainly have no reason to complain about it.

Comment: I don't think he is complaining. It sounds more like he needs help understanding the internals of the protocol. On the face value you are not attempting to answer the question in your answer. This might be better as a comment.